# Simplest way of finding the coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

What's the simplest way to find the coefficient of $r^3bg^2$ in $3(r+b+g)^2(r^2+b^2+g^2)^2$?

Comment: the calculation is simple!

Comment: are you sure about $r^3bg^2$?

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question down wrong originally, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to write an expanded form of the problem:

$3(r+b+g)(r^2+b^2+g^2)(r+b+g)(r^2+b^2+g^2)$

Next we see what combination of multiplication could lead to a power of $r^3$. which is $r * r^2$. Next step is to see the power of $b$ which is $b$ and $g^2$ which is $g^2$.

Therefore the number of terms of multiplication that can produce such a combination is:

(number of single power brackets) * (number of 2 power brackets) * (number of single brackets left) * (number of 2 power brackets left)

Which equals:

$\binom{2}{1} * \binom{2}{1} * \binom{2}{0} * \binom{2}{0} = 4$

That means we will have at least 4 terms. That also means that the coefficient of the total of the terms, which is $4 * 3$, leading to a final coefficient of **12**.